How Do I Get the Least Degree that Gives a Regular Sequence?
Definition 1: Let $A$ be a commutative ring. A sequence of elements $a_1,…,a_t$ of $A$ is called a regular sequence if:
(1) $\langle a_1,…,a_t\rangle$ is a proper ideal of $A$.
(2) $a_1$ is not a zero divisor in $A$.
(3) $\tilde{a_i}$ is not a zero divisor in $A/\langle a_1,…,a_{i-1}\rangle$
Definition 2: Let $\alpha=\alpha(J)$ be the least degree of a non-zero form in $J$, where $J$ is a homogeneous ideal for which $\sqrt{J}=(x_0,x_1,x_2)$.
Definition 3: Let $X$ be a set of points in $\mathbb{P}^2, I=I(X)$. We define $\beta (I)$ to be the least integer $d$ for which $I_d$ contains a regular sequence of length 2.
Question
Suppose $X=\begin{Bmatrix}
o&o&o&o&o\\
o
\end{Bmatrix}$, the Hilbert function yields 1,3,4,5,6,6,…
Now, $\alpha=2$ and $\beta=5$. I don’t know how to show that $\beta=2,3,4$ will not work, and that $\beta=5$ works.
Note
I understand if $I=\langle F,G\rangle$, then $F$ and $G$ should be relatively prime (if $F$ and $G$ form a regular sequence). That $\beta$ is the least degree of $I$ for which this will be achieved. However, I don’t seem to know how to convince myself in this case that $\beta=5$, and that the values of $\beta$ less than 5 will not work.
Note
It seems obvious to me that $\beta=2$ will not work. Let $I=\langle F,G\rangle$. If we draw a horizontal line $\mathcal{l_1}$ through the five points in the first row, a horizontal line $\mathcal{l_2}$ through the two points in the second row, and a vertical line $\mathcal{l_3}$ through the two points in the first column. It seems we will have $F=\mathcal{l_1}\mathcal{l_3}$ and $G=\mathcal{l_1}\mathcal{l_2}$, say. So, $F$ and $G$ have $\mathcal{l_1}$ as a common factor. However, I will appreciate an algebraic approach that shows $\beta=2,3,4$ will not work, and that $\beta=5$ will work.

Is $X$ the configuration where 5 points are on one line and one point outside? Is that what you mean?

@cqfd Yes, that is what I mean.

Well then I am pretty sure that the ideal requires three generators.
